# Pandas how to convert the timezone for a column

Tags: python, pandas

In my pandas dataframe I need to convert the CREATED column from UTC time to Asia/Hong_Kong (8 hour difference). I need to use pytz, instead of declaring + 8 hours. I am aware **dt** can accomplish this, however for this script the new version of pandas cannot be used.

```
ID          CREATED
234         2017-03-16 17:18:20
720         2017-03-15 22:09:13    
639         2017-03-16 04:49:12
```

I am able to localize the CREATED column, however I am not having any luck on the **conversion** part.

```
import pytz
tz_utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
tz_hkg = pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')

def localize_utc(x):
    if not isinstance(x, pd.tslib.NaTType):
        return tz_utc.localize(x) 
    return None

df['CREATED'] = df['CREATED'].apply(lambda x: localize_utc(x))
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we have the following DF:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
    ID             CREATED
0  234 2017-03-16 17:18:20
1  720 2017-03-15 22:09:13
2  639 2017-03-16 04:49:12
```

we can convert TZ as follows:

```
In [32]: df['CREATED'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Hong_Kong')
Out[32]:
0   2017-03-17 01:18:20+08:00
1   2017-03-16 06:09:13+08:00
2   2017-03-16 12:49:12+08:00
Name: CREATED, dtype: datetime64[ns, Asia/Hong_Kong]
```

Comment: yes that works, however I am looking to see if I can do it without "dt" (using older pandas version)